# Always get UNKNOWN status code for failed gRPCs to python server

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

my data.proto likes this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package rpc;
service Performer {
  rpc carryOut(Image) returns (Objects){}
}

message Objects{
    repeated Object objects=1;
}

message Object{
    string type=1;
}
```

and implementation like this:

```
class Performer(data_pb2_grpc.PerformerServicer):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def carryOut(self, req, cxt):
         objs=Objects()
         obj=objs.objects.add()
         obj.type='Person'
         return objs
```

client request always get:

```
    self.res = self.client().carryOut(self.data()) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 484, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 434, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNKNOWN, Stream removed)>
```

and server crash with error:
  Segmentation fault(written dump)

and it happens in a laptop with :

```
 ubuntu 16.04
 python 2.7.12
 grpcio==1.8.4
 grpcio-tools==1.8.4
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of Image and the source for the self.data() call on the client?

Comment: @ago,thanks,I have found where the problem come from:my actuallcarryOut() is more complex,where has a pointer is freed twice,after moving an memory allocation from another method to carryOut() itself,the exception stack got printed out,before that only "Segmentation fault(written dump)" got printed out